# How to Show different options at no agent depending on Menu selection?

Tags: einstein, einstein-chatbot

When there no agent , the bot routes to this general dialog

But for example the users selects Menu Option A --> when it routes to no agent --> I would like to show different options such as

for Option A --> Create a case

if User is at Option B --> and no agent ---> show the user create a case but different wording (routing to different dialog to show different wording )

How can we achieve this ?

﻿
[image]
﻿

Can we store the menu selection ? to put in variable checks here ?

How can we differentiate from which dialog it is routed to no agent and show different options as per the dialog selection ?

Please guide me

thanks